# Dev Tools popup with error regarding status bar in Atom using Linter Ruby

Tags: atom-editor

In OSX 10.9.4, Using Atom with Linter and Linter Ruby packages installed and enabled, and there are linters displayed indicating an error in the written code, the Developer Tools window pops up, with multiple "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" errors, in statusbar-view.coffee, at line 98 "if editor.getLastCursor()?".  This breaks the status bar info (where normally linter would give useful info), freezing where it was when the initial error occurs.

I have no other packages installed in Atom, and attempted reinstalling both packages, and this is a very clean computer otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This was simply an issue with Atom not being updated, due to the app's permissions not being set properly.